# rails tire gem elasticsearch not working properly with will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to integrate Tire into my site and I'm having difficulty with pagination. I've tried paginating the results outside of the context of Tire and `will_paginate` is working on that Array. However, when I try `will_paginate` within the context of Tire I'm having one large problem.

`Will_Paginate` will display the correct number of pages with consideration of :per_page but when I click on that page the results are not loaded, rather they are the same as on the first page. The page number is highlighted in the `will_paginate` navigation.

Comment: Please post your code. The docs show an example and it's very straightforward to integrate (https://github.com/karmi/retire).

Answer (score 0):

When I used the per_page option, I had similar issue. So, I shifted to the from size options provided by Tire. I'm not sure what went wrong. But, explicitly setting and using from and size did the trick for me...

```
 def search
    options = { :page => (params[:page] || 1), :size => 100 }
    query = params[:query]
    @results = Tire.search ['index_name'], options do
      query { string query }
      from options[:size].to_i * (options[:page].to_i-1)
    end
  end
```